# Durrett 5th Edition Example 1.1.6

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Example 1.1.6 in Durrett 5th edition is trying to show an example in which the converse of the statement "A $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra" is false. I do not quite get why the example shows that the converse of the statement is false. That is, I do not get why $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

[image]

Comment: There are two questions here (i) why $\cal A$ is an algebra, (ii) why $\cal A$ is not a sigma-algebra. Which is causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each nonnegative integer $n$ define the singleton $A_n=\{2n\}$. Although each $A_n$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, the unión of these sets, which is the set of all even positive integers $P=\{2n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, is not for neither $P$ nor $P^c$ is finite.

That $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra is not difficult to check: if $A$ and $B$ belong to $\mathcal{A}$, then either $A\cup B$ is finite, or $A^c\cap B^c$ is finite.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering! I am a bit confused about why each $A_{n}$ is in $\mathcal{A}$. For example, if $n=1$, then $A_{1}=\{2\}$, then $A^{c}_{1}=\mathbb{Z}\backslash A_{1}$ which is NOT finite. So $A^{c}_{1}$ is NOT in $\mathcal{A}$ and then $A_{1}$ can not be in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: $A_n$ is finite (it has only one element) and so $A_n\in\mathcal{A}$. By definition, $A\in\mathcal{A}$ iff $A$ is finite OR $A^c=\mathbb{Z}\setminus A$ is finite. Notice the difference between OR and AND.

Comment: Got it! Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra, consider the sets
$$
A_n=\{2n+1\},
$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Every such set is finite, so $A_n\in\mathcal{A}$, for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. But
$$
A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}A_n=\{2m+1:m\in\mathbb{Z}\}
$$
doesn't belong to $\mathcal{A}$, because neither $A$ or $\mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus A$ is finite. So $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering the questions! I am wondering why each $A_{n}\in\mathcal{A}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. For example if $n=1$, you have $A_{1}={3}$ which is finite but, $A^{c}_{1}=\mathbb{Z}\backslash A_{1}$ is NOT finite so it does not belong to $\mathcal{A}$, then $A_{1}$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$.